# Get value only from float

Tags: javascript, math

We have 2 numbers that we dont know if it has decimals or not. I need difference of those value.

For example:

**0.76544** and **0.76432**. I need **112** as result from this 2 number.

**13053** and **13023** numbers.. I need **30** result from this 2 number.

I think, this is more of string modifying then math actually. If there is something like **0.00** or any dot.. just remove.

(For those that know forex, this is need for pips value)

Comment: You need to elaborate on your problem more. What exactly are you trying to do? You say *"we dont know if it has decimals or not"* so what happens in the case where you don't have decimals?

Comment: Seems you want to take the difference between the two numbers, and then treat the resulting digits as an integer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: You are also going to run into the problem of how floating point numbers are represented. `0.76544 - 0.76432` isn't `0.00112`, it's `0.0011200000000000099`

Comment: Lets say we have 13053 and 13023 numbers.. i need just 30 result. Difference between 2 numbers only.

Comment: But the difference *is* 0.00112, it's not 112. You seem to want to redefine mathematics

Comment: Multiply numbers by 100,000, convert to integers and subtract

Comment: @CharlesBretana: and if the result is > 100,000, you'll need to divide again

Comment: And what would be the behavior if you had, for example, `2.112 - 1.011`?

Comment: I even thought of converting to string and erase 0.00 section if any has.. lol.

Comment: @MattBurland good question but numbers are really really close in my problem.. Still i dont know if its floating or not.. You can think forex currency pairs.. some goes like 0.35532, some goes like 32342.32

Comment: Pip size is consistent: 0.01 for any JPY pair and 0.0001 for everything else. What you described is something different.

Comment: Do you also want to tag this with [tag:forex]?  It looked from googling that you're always multiplying by 10^2 or 10^4, is this true?  Do you get the input numbers as strings, or are they already converted to floats?

Comment: @Teepeemm Just 2 numbers that we dont know if has decimal or not (those numbers are float, not int or strings. I need 2 number's difference as value like in question example. I am not sure what you are saying by multiplying by 10^2 but no.

Comment: It's similar to Ray Radin's comment: pips are 0.01 if JPY is involved, and pips are 0.0001 otherwise.  If that's the case, then you can multiply by 100 if JPY is involved, and multiply by 10,000 otherwise, and then take the difference of the resulting integers.  But your example would involve multiplying by 100,000, so either my googling was wrong (entirely possible, since I've never heard of pips), or your example is mistaken.

Comment: First of all, XAUUSD (gold) price as example: 1133.17. See? its not 0.0001. Whoever say to you that you can generalize all pips, its mistaken imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work? I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what you are asking.

```
var num1 = '0.76544';
var num2 = '0.76432';

num1 = parseInt(num1.replace(/\./, ''));
num2 = parseInt(num2.replace(/\./, ''));

alert(num1 - num2);
```

This assumes your starting values are strings. If they are not, you will need to convert them to strings to have access to the prototype method `replace`.

Here is a link to a working jsFiddle that you can play with. https://jsfiddle.net/v280824w/. Please let me know if I missed something in your question. Good luck.

Comment: Haha thanks! When trying to find complicated solution, this one came like heaven-sent :) I couldnt give you bounty, need to wait 1 hour it seems.